# HttpURLConnection respond 404 when file clearly exist

Tags: java

I have a java program that is trying to read any arbitrary file from URL.  However, it return an 404 error when the file clearly exist, try it for yourself with the URL.  What is wrong?

```
      URL url = new URL("http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/blue_abstract_background_310971.jpg");
      HttpURLConnection myHTTPConTest = null;
      myHTTPConTest = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      int responseCode = myHTTPConTest.getResponseCode();  // Returns 404
```

Added user-agent, no change:

```
      myHTTPConTest.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401");
```

Comment: could be a matter of user-agent

Comment: I ran the program and it returns a response code of 200.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, is there any other setting?  I also tried to add user-agent but no change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a bad luck and you just hit the server restart time or something like that.
Because it returns 200 now.

Comment: No, that is not the case because I tried it quite a few times.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It works I tried in my box. Did you try that url from browser?

Comment: Oh, it turned out company is blocking that domain.  No wonder.